# How to apply .onHover to individual elements in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, onhover

I am trying to animate individual items on mouseover. The issue I am having is that *every* item gets animated on mouseover of an item instead of just that specific item.
Here is what I have:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var hovered = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 90) {
            ForEach(0..<2) {_ in
                HStack(spacing: 90) {
                    ForEach(0..<4) {_ in
                        Circle().fill(Color.red).frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .scaleEffect(self.hovered ? 2.0 : 1.0)
                        .animation(.default)
                        .onHover { hover in
                                print("Mouse hover: \(hover)")
                            self.hovered.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth:300,maxWidth:.infinity,minHeight:300,maxHeight:.infinity)
    }
}
```

[image: drawing]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It needs to change onHover view on per-view base, ie. store some identifier of hovered view.

Here is possible solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4.

[image: demo]

```
struct TestOnHoverInList : View {
    @State var hovered: (Int, Int) = (-1, -1)
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 90) {
            ForEach(0..<2) {i in
                HStack(spacing: 90) {
                    ForEach(0..<4) {j in
                        Circle().fill(Color.red).frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .scaleEffect(self.hovered == (i,j) ? 2.0 : 1.0)
                        .animation(.default)
                        .onHover { hover in
                            print("Mouse hover: \(hover)")
                            if hover {
                                self.hovered = (i, j)    // << here !!
                            } else {
                                self.hovered = (-1, -1)  // reset
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth:300,maxWidth:.infinity,minHeight:300,maxHeight:.infinity)
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I use this on a LazyVgrid ???

Answer (score 5):

Every item currently gets animated because they are all relying on `hovered` to see if the `Circle` is hovered over. To fix that, we can make every circle have their own `hovered` state.

```
struct CircleView: View {
    @State var hovered = false

    var body: some View {
        Circle().fill(Color.red).frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .scaleEffect(self.hovered ? 2.0 : 1.0)
        .animation(.default)
        .onHover { hover in
                print("Mouse hover: \(hover)")
            self.hovered.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

and in the `ForEach` we can just call the new `CircleView` where every `Circle` has their own source of truth.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 90) {
            ForEach(0..<2) { _ in
                HStack(spacing: 90) {
                    ForEach(0..<4) { _ in
                        CircleView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth:300,maxWidth:.infinity,minHeight:300,maxHeight:.infinity)
    }
}
```

Comment: with this method, you would have to hover again so it scales down, it doesn't auto scales down when out of hover...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create a modifier that allows you to change the View in question when it's hovered:

```swift
extension View {
    func onHover<Content: View>(@ViewBuilder _ modify: @escaping (Self) -> Content) -> some View {
        modifier(HoverModifier { modify(self) })
    }
}

private struct HoverModifier<Result: View>: ViewModifier {
    @ViewBuilder let modifier: () -> Result
    @State private var isHovering = false

    func body(content: Content) -> AnyView {
        (isHovering ? modifier().eraseToAnyView() : content.eraseToAnyView())
            .onHover { self.isHovering = $0 }
            .eraseToAnyView()
    }
}
```

Then each Circle on your example would go something like:

```swift
Circle().fill(Color.red).frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    .animation(.default)
    .onHover { view in
        _ = print("Mouse hover")
        view.scaleEffect(2.0)
    }
```