# onHover() does not function SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to work with onHover(); I want my foreground color to change when I move the cursor on top of the Text(), but it did not work.

Why?

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {

@State private var overText = false

var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!")
        .foregroundColor(overText ? .green : .red)
        .onHover { over in
            overText = over
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Next should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/61607286/12299030, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61985678/12299030. Btw, if something does not work it is needed to mention in which environment, version, etc, because it might be system issue.

Comment: Appreciated once again. I will try it out.

Comment: FYI, works well for me on macos 13, using Xcode 14, targets ios-15 macCatalyst and macos only.
Does not work for me on ios-15 only devices.

Comment: Interesting because I just downloaded Xcode 14, and tried the same thing, but onHover() still did not work.

Comment: what system, target and what device are you using?

Comment: IOS 15, Xcode 14, lastest macOS, M1 chip.

Comment: I checked up other developers who have contents about onHover() around March-April 2022, they have the same code and it worked, but mine not. idk why, I switched up many version and target already.